# Previewing documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, preview

I am curious in knowing whether it is even possible to have a webpart to display document previews for word, excel, pdf being the main one. The scenario will be that in a "Document library" for example when clicking selecting on a document, a preview of the first page of the document is shown on a webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Vizit](http://www.vizit.com/). They have a product and an associated API for doing document previews.

Answer (score 0):

these links will help [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-document-management-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) &
[link2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-document-management-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) u can get an idea...

Comment: Two links to the same content... Not helpfull